# DB2 column type that could represent 25 hours or more

Tags: time, db2, sqldatatypes, custom-data-type

I would like to know a DB2 column type that could represent 25 hours or more as TIME have a limited range of 0 to 24 hours.

Comment: INTEGER, if you store the number of seconds (or whatever precision you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically time duration is stored as an integer data type representing the number of time units appropriate for your precision requirements. One common example is the Unix time, which is the number of seconds since 1 January, 1970.

Internally DB2 implements duration (for example, when you subtract one `TIME` value from another) as a `DECIMAL`, so this is a good option if you plan to perform arithmetic operations between DB2 `TIME` and your duration value. To quote the [manual](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023457.html):

> A time duration represents a number of hours, minutes, and seconds, expressed as a DECIMAL(6,0) number. To be properly interpreted, the number must have the format hhmmss., where hh represents the number of hours, mm the number of minutes, and ss the number of seconds.

Comment: I have some apps with mysql where it is implemented with TIME datatype where I can insert 25:00:00 for example and somehow I could not rethink on this simple solution. Thanks for the promted response, that is exactly what I need!

Comment: If you look at [how MySQL implements the `TIME` data type](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server/blob/5.7/include/my_time.h), you'll see a DB2's duration. Semantically though "time", as in time of day, and "duration" should be different, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is to implement an UDT: User Defined Type. With an UDT you can perform operation on this datatype. As @mustaccio has said, the best thing is to implement this as a decimal.

- https://www.toadworld.com/platforms/ibmdb2/w/wiki/7675.user-defined-data-types-udt
- http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/c0006438.html